# Not sure how to initialise the database connection

Tags: c#, button, database-connection, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into my SQL database table called Questions, whenever I click on the button the error below comes up and I'm not sure how to solve this problem as I thought I only needed to open the database connection then close it afterwards?

Any help would be very helpful.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (1)");
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connect.Close();

    }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is clear;

You did not connect your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`. Use your connection as a second parameter in your command like;

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (1)",
                                      connect);
```

Or you can use [`CreateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you create your `SqlCommand` based on your connection. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automaticly instead of calling `.Close()` method manually.

Best way possible;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    using(var connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var command1 = connect.CreateCommand())
    {
         command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (1)";
         connect.Open();
         command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall tick this answer when I can, could you please give me an example of the CreateCommand if you don't mind?

Comment: @mot375 I just did. Take a look.